# Interacting with the Chrome V8 debugger protocol through .NET (ClearScript)

Tags: c#, .net, v8, remote-debugging, clearscript

I'm maintaining an enterprise C# application that provides end-user extensibility through user-defined JavaScript functions (with a select few C# types/proxies exposed) (think financial algorithms).

We evaluate those functions using [ClearScript](https://github.com/microsoft/ClearScript) (prevously we were using another library called Noesis however we've moved away from that).

I'd like to offer a way for **end-users** to perform very basic debugging of the scripts (through a web interface). At a minimum - inspect variables and step over/into functions.

I've successfully connected to the ClearScript engine w/ Chrome when running the app locally and have been able to step through the scripts - however I don't think the same would make sense for end users whilst running in production for various reasons:

- Might be too tricky for them to set up
- Possible difficulties with port allocation
- Probable firewall issues

What I'd really like is a SignalR interface to the V8 debugger - the web-app would interact with the SignalR, and SignalR would interact with the V8 debugger.

- Has anyone done something along these lines before?
- Are there any relevant .NET libraries I should be looking at?
- Am I right in my thoughts that this seems like a fairly big piece of work?
- Any other advice?

Comment: I've just seen https://github.com/buggerjs/bugger-v8-client which might be relevant as a reference client (JavaScript).

Comment: Also https://github.com/dtretyakov/node-tools/wiki/Debugging-Protocol

Comment: The concern about port _allocation_ difficulty comes from the possibility of mutiple users trying to debug ClearScript simultaneously - each of the V8 instances would need to be listening on a different port (we'd need to allow all of those ports through the firewall). Having enough high-numbered ports to choose from is still going to be a challenge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a web-socket based protocol - though you must make a request via HTTP to retrieve the tabId first (request to `/json/list`)

https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/1-2/Debugger describes the protocol - there are different revisions targetting different versions of Chrome but 1.2 (stable) seems to work w/ the version of ClearScript I used.

As well as request-response (command) type interactions on the websocket, V8 will also publish events - e.g. `Debugger.scriptParsed` & `Debugger.paused` on the same socket.

Some of the key commands:
`Runtime.enable`
`Debugger.enable`
`Runtime.runIfWaitingForDebugger`
`Debugger.getScriptSource`
`Debugger.resume`
`Debugger.evaluateOnCallFrame`
`Runtime.getProperties`

I've written a small demo project https://github.com/flakey-bit/ClearScriptDebugging/ that shows a target process being debugged by another process.

Comment: There's also a project called https://github.com/BaristaLabs/chrome-dev-tools-runtime which looks pretty similar to what I ended up implementing.

Comment: I've also blogged on my findings here: https://eddiewould.com/2019/05/26/using-net-to-interact-with-the-chrome-v8-debugger-running-in-clearscript/

Answer (score 0):

If you mentioned Chrome and Nodejs, You maybe know that Nodejs, Chrome and Edge support WebSocket naturally. Chrome and Edge better with all security options. For Nodejs you can find standard libraries like socket.io
  For the server side [DotNet WebSocket](https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp)
WebSocket protocol is linga franka today.